# Weird versioning problems with AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just upgraded to Amazon's latest SDK, 2.0.13.2.  Unfortunately, I'm now having a problem with the `Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest` class.  It refuses to recognize a `Timeout` property.  If I have

```
Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = newFileName,
    ContentType = packet.ContentType,
    InputStream = new MemoryStream(packet.Buffer)
};
```

then all works well.  But as soon as I add

```
titledRequest.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
```

it **still compiles** but blows up at runtime with

> Method not found: 'Void Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest.set_Timeout(System.Nullable`1)'.

What's especially frustrating is that if I comment out the line that sets Timeout, and step into the method that sets this all up, I can click on `Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest`, hit F-12 and look at the type's Metadata, and clearly see the Timeout property.  Yet if I try to ever use it, or even look at the property in the quick watch window, I get the error above.

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, uninstalling and re-installing AWSSDK with NuGet, and even re-booting.  Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my own answer in the incredibly small chance someone else has a similar problem.

Our many various projects had wildly differing .net versions—3.5, 4.0 and 4.5.  As such, with NuGet trying to sort out which version to give which project, it turns out the compiler thought I was on an older version of the AWSSDK that had this timeout property on the PutObjectRequest object, while at runtime we were hitting the most recent, which does *not* have this property, hence the runtime error.

Comment: it might be the other way round: the latest version as of today v3 of the sdk *has* the TimeOut property on the PutObjectRequest: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html